# Not enough readable bytes - Need 4, maximum is 0

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, database, nosql

While connecting to Cassandra Database and creating a keyspace I am getting the following error.

> Exception in thread "main"  > com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:
>   All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Unexpected error during transport initialization
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Unexpected exception triggered (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Not enough readable bytes - Need 4, maximum is 0))))

This is my code:

```
package com.hadoop.reloaded.cassandra;

import com.datastax.driver.core.*;

public class CassandraOne {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Cluster cluster1 = Cluster.builder().withPort(9042).addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
        Session session = cluster1.connect();
        String query = "CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication "
                + "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1}; ";
        session.execute(query);
        session.execute("USE test");

    }
}
```

and this exception throws when i run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (
    com.datastax.driver.core.ConnectionException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] 
        Unexpected error during transport initialization (
            com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042]
                Unexpected exception triggered (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Not enough readable bytes - Need 4, maximum is 0))))

    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:196)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1104)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:121)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:198)
    at com.hadoop.reloaded.cassandra.CassandraOne.main(CassandraOne.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: What version of the datastax java driver are you using, and also what version of Cassandra?

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8 and Cassansdra 3.7 versions

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are using a version of the Datastax Java Driver that is too old.  Check to see if you are running version 3.0.0 or later as this is required to connect to a Cassandra 3.X cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, after upgrade driver to `cassandra-driver-core-3.0.3.jar`
and netty as this picture. issue has resolved
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe encoding issue ?

More détails on [this link](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1132)